# Cardinality of members of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have to count all the words in a book. I need the cardinality (occurrence) of all the words. `{{Table,30},{the,200},{apple29}`, etc...

I **Split**ted, and **StringTrim**ed and **LowerCase**d, now I have like this: {"there", "is", "a", "table", "on", "the", "table", "put", "it", "on", "the", "table"} Lenght is not good, because its not for 1 word, but for the whole text.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You are looking for [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {"there", "is", "a", "table", "on", "the", "table", "put", "it", "on", "the", "table"};

count = Tally@list
```

> {{"there", 1}, {"is", 1}, {"a", 1}, {"table", 3}, {"on", 2}, {"the",
>   2}, {"put", 1}, {"it", 1}}

```
Reverse@SortBy[Last]@count // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringSplit to trim and separate the words:

```
a = ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}];
Sort[Counts[StringSplit[a]], Greater][[1 ;; 10]]
```

Result:

```
<|"of" -> 79, "the" -> 76, "to" -> 64, "and" -> 55, "our" -> 25, 
 "has" -> 20, "their" -> 20, "for" -> 19, "He" -> 18, "in" -> 18|>
```

Now when counting words, the majority of the time you wont want the useless words so you can use DeleteStopwords to remove filler or connector words.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [`WordCounts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCounts.html):

```
text = ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}];
WordCounts[text]
(*
  <|"of" -> 79, "the" -> 76, "to" -> 64, "and" -> 55, "our" -> 25, 
   "their" -> 20, "has" -> 20, "for" -> 19, "in" -> 18, "He" -> 18,... \>
*)
```

Or you may prefer

```
WordCounts[ToLowerCase@text]
```